# Can I make external styles outside of blazor CSS isolation?

Tags: css, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a website with Header, Main, Footer styles divided into blocks, etc. and it looks something like this:

[image: Style site]

In Style, I import all this and link it to html (and I use preprocessor)

```
@import "Core.css"
@import "Header/Header.css"
@import "Main/Main.css"
@import "Footer/Footer.css"
@import "etc and so on"
```

So I decided to move my site to Blazor and use the separation of styles into blocks on it, it turned out something like this:

[image: Blazor site]

It just turned out that all styles are in a static folder, and imports are in isolation of MainLayout.style.

And if connect styles in a static index, then imports in isolation will not be needed.

And now my questions:

1. Is it possible to do this and does it correspond to the Blazor Style Guide?
2. If I can't do this, then how is it better to do this?
3. If I can do this, then how is it better to do this?
4. If I make a MainLayout into a preprocessor that will output css, will it be better than the above options?

Comment: Try to read this https://edcharbeneau.com/2021-04-24-setting-up-sass-with-blazor/ 
I use SASS but CSS isolations works pretty good with NET 6 and hot reload.
But I think you can use stylus in the same way as SASS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, no one answered, so I will write my answer to my question.

I split MainLayout into two parts - HeaderLayout and FooterLayout, made CSS isolation and in MainLayout I put them together.

[image: Split MainLayout]
[image: MainLayout]

And use pseudo-class ::deep for child component support (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#child-component-support).

I think my solution correspond to Blazor Style Guide and in general it is quite effective.